# Can all computers open TCP/IP sockets?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, ipc

Can any and all computers open network sockets locally, specifically TCP/IP sockets? Even computers that don't have a network interface such as an Ethernet port or a WiFi antenna?

I want to perform interprocess communication (IPC). I am aware there are IPC sockets, so this question is asking more in the context of TCP/IP sockets.

Comment: There are computers (e.g. on embedded devices) whose operating systems do not include a TCP/IP stack -- any program written to use TCP/IP APIs will be unlikely to work on those.

Comment: Why do you care whether they're TCP/IP or not if there's no network interface?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I want to build a request and response architecture. What better way to do that than through the multitude of web servers written out there? I _could_ build my own request/response protocol on top of IPC, but TCP seems like a saner choice. Theoretically IPC is supported everywhere whereas TCP I had doubts on... Hence me asking this question.

Comment: It seems to me that all you need is a bidirectional stream. If you don't need any TCP-specific features, why insist on TCP specifically?

Comment: A stream would be ok, but I am making specific calls to specific functions in a request + response format. The reason why I'm insisting on request + response is because traditionally in IPC if there is an error, you cannot provide an error back. Making a call from Java to C and only getting something like a `-1` as an error isn't good enough, I want a message regarding the error and perhaps something like a status code - thus leading me back to webservers. I am aware that tools like Swig and JNI exist to perform IPC communication in a reasonable manner, but such tools are highly complex.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the [loopback IP network interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is available. You should be able to send to and receive from host `localhost` using TCP, UDP and raw IP sockets; run a web-server or any other TCP/IP server locally.

Comment: Thanks for the link. What if the computer does not include a network stack? Will the loopback interface still be available?

Comment: @gurpreet- Well, you need to ask the person who configured the kernel/OS. If your OS is Linux based, try `ifconfig` command to see what interfaces are available. May be you can use [UNIX sockets](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html).